# Convert int to string with dots java

Tags: java

How do I convert int to string with dots seperating in a certain pattern?

example:

```
int number = 12312300:
```

would become

```
"123.123.0.0";
```

I've looked at DecimalFormat and split to divide, but to no success.

EDIT:

As menetioned by a few of you, here is a more detailed explanation.

the format will stay as XXX.XXX.X.X.

so ex:

```
int number = 12312300;
```

converted to String:

```
String = "123.123.0.0";
number++;
```

so next time the method gets called the number is:

```
int number = 12312301;
```

which again becomes when converted to String:

```
String = "123.123.0.1";
```

Comment: Could you clarify on the pattern you are trying to achieve.

Comment: the pattern would look like an ip address basically. xxx.xxx.x.x is the pattern im looking for.

Comment: There are ambiguous cases.  How would you know, for example, if `123012` is `12.30.1.2` instead of `123.0.1.2`?

Comment: @e0k it's mainly going to be used to get 10 cases of xxx.xxx.x.x where I +1 on the last digit. I know it's not a good method of doing it, but it's what I need as of now for resting purposes.

Comment: ...Are you trying to create an IP address?

Comment: @KTown Please add more detail to your question regarding these "10 cases" and doing a "+ 1 on the last digit". As e0k pointed out, your pattern of `xxx.xxx.x.x` has multiple interpretations like `1.230.1.2`

Comment: Poor question gets poor results

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Convert to String with `Integer.toString(number);`
Then you can use the substring method of the String class to split your String into the seperate parts. Finally you can just add them together with the + operator. For example = ss1 + "." + ss2 + "." and so on.

```
String s = Integer.toString(number);
//change this part so it matches the format you want to achieve
s = s.substring(0,2) + "." + s.substring(3,5) "." + s.substring(6,6);
```

This would basically work, but if your String is not long enough, the substring method will throw an exception at runtime. So you'll have to check the size of the String first.

Answer (score -2):

Use this function:

```
public void convert()
{
    int [] num = new int[3];
    String str = null;
    int number = 123012; 
    for (int i=0; i <num.length;i++)
    {
     num[i] = number%10;
     number = number/10;
    }
    str = number+"."+num[2]+"."+num[1]+"."+num[0];
    System.out.println(str);
}
```